# How to know that an app is going to be uninstalled in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to implement something like AppLock application is doing.
If in its settings it is set to lock applications uninstall/install, then while uninstalling any app (precisely on clicking the **Uninstall** button) a lock screen comes which asks for a password/pattern.
Only after entering the password user is allowed to uninstall the app.

What's that intent(or anything, I assume it to be an intent but not sure) that one get when **Uninstall button** is clicked?
Also **I dont want to make it device admin, as the app I mentioned does require to be device admin.**
If they can do it, then there is some way.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way.

1. When you go to **Settings** -> **Manage Apps** -> **Click on any app**. 
   you get a broadcast with name of the package in extras.
2. When you click on the **Uninstall** button on that screen,
   an activity is opened always name **`com.android.uninstaller.UnistallerActivity`**.

So the solution to this problem is a combined way of 1 and 2 steps mentioned above.

When ever you get the intent mentioned in first step and the extras contain the package name of your app start an activity watcher using `PackageManager` by which you get the top most visible activity and its package.
So now if uninstaller activity is launched then you can be sure that user wants to uninstall your app.

There after you can do necessary action to stop him to do that.

Comment: My above mentioned solution fails on the devices that provide the functionality to uninstall the app from app drawer itself. Above mentioned solution works well when one tries to uninstall the app from settings -> manage apps and then uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a device administrator instead. That will automatically block the user from uninstalling it. If the user tries to deactivate it from the Security > Device Administrator list in order to uninstall it, your app can then ask for the password.

Comment: but apps are being able to do the required job even without making it device admin. How is that even possible. Is there some kinda hack, some reflection used to unexposed code of android??

Comment: Any other way is a hackjob that involves detecting when other Activities are launched. There will always be a delay or screen flicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the intent for your application uninstall. Simply put the following code in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".UninstallActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:pathPattern="com.package.yourapp" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
</application>
```

After this you can somehow process that your application is going to be deleted, and call the package manager uninstaller.

Comment: @Jaguar:  It says the permissions you mentioned are avilable only for system apps. Now how to make my app as a system app???

Comment: @akkilis Try cleaning the project

Comment: What next ?? I am not able to figure out the next step. I am not getting any sort of notification that my app is going to be removed.

Comment: In the logs I can see this exception :  E/InstalledAppDetails(21184): Exception when retrieving package:com.example.appuninstall

Comment: also, there is printed : 
W/ContextImpl(21353): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1352 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:450 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2376

Answer (score 0):

try catching below intent in the broadcast reciver and fire up ur activity warning activity or processing what u want to carry on.

"android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE"

this intent will not given or broadcasted to same app which is about to get uninstalled

Comment: its working but only on pre ICS devices. Reason being since ICS you can set setPackage(required package) to the intent you are broadcasting. Hence I am not getting it on ICS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has gone through a lot of changes. The default broadcast of `PACKAGE_REMOVED` doesn't work as intended. I came across this discussion, did not actually implement it, but people say it has worked for them. Do give this a try

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/aX5-fMbdPR8

Answer (score 0):

try this code

Please try to get the top activity in the task via ActivityManager, and check if it is the uninstall activity.

```
 ComponentName topActivity = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
String packageName = topActivity.getPackageName();
String className = topActivity.getClassName();
Log.v(TAG, "packageName" + packageName);
Log.v(TAG, "className" + className);

if ("com.android.packageinstaller".equals(packageName)
    && "com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity".equals(className)) {
//Do anything you want here
}
```

như lone