# Deleting fields on a server DB

Tags: android, database

I'm doing an Android app that has a database hosted on a server.
When you run the app for the first time, you must register and data is stored on the server.

I would like to delete the user on the server when uninstalling the app of his/her device.

Is this possible?

Comment: Find more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431922/how-to-know-that-an-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled-in-android
Looks like it works in some cases

Comment: Isn't any answer helped you? If you got any solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.

Answer (score 0):

[Perform a task on uninstall in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013823/perform-a-task-on-uninstall-in-android)
sorry bro, that is not possible.
You just can make 3weeks clearing databases since last login in

Comment: Thanks, but i can't delete users from the database if i am not sure that the user has uninstalled the app

Comment: some times we need to make some evristic algorithms, in you case i seggest you to clean user table after some time he is offline

Answer (score 0):

As per **[Android Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)**

> Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been removed from the device. The data contains the name of the package. The package that is being installed does not receive this Intent.

**Conclusion**

Not Possible

**Suggestion**

You can put some **Remove Account** type of screen or menu inside your application. You can hope user to do that before uninstalling.